# Referencing inserted ID in multiple insert transactions in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, foreign-keys, relational-database

I need to build a SQL query that must be able to insert data in a first table, grab the inserted ID and then use it as foreign key in the following tables.

```
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO firstTable (name) VALUES ('somename') RETURNING id
)

SELECT * FROM inserted; -- this has the inserted id

INSERT INTO secondTable (name, foreign_id) VALUES ('someexternalname', ???)
```

So how do I reference the `id` in `inserted` in the `secondTable` insert?

Answer (score 3):

You have completed this 80% percent, the complete SQL is:

```
with inserted as (
 insert into first_table(name) values ('somename') returning id
)
insert into second_table(name, foreign_id) select 'someexternalname',id from inserted
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO firstTable (name) VALUES ('somename') RETURNING id
)

INSERT INTO secondTable (name, foreign_id)
SELECT
'someexternalname',
id
FROM inserted;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO secondTable (name, foreign_id) VALUES ('someexternalname', (SELECT 
MAX (id) FROM firstTable))
```